# protractor ElementArrayFinder .last() [object Object] has no method 'indexof'

Tags: angularjs, automated-tests, protractor, angularjs-e2e

i'm trying to run through the tutorial  http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial

when i try to get element using `.first()` or `.last()` method
the test failed with error:

> TypeError Object [object Object] has no method 'indexof'

here is spec.js

```
var firstNumber = element(by.model('first'));
var secondNumber = element(by.model('second'));
var go = element(by.id('gobutton'));
var latest = element(by.binding('latest'));
var history = element.all(by.repeater('result in memory'));

beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
});
//...other tests passed

it('should have a history', function(){
    firstNumber.sendKeys(1);
    secondNumber.sendKeys(2);
    go.click();

    expect(history.count()).toEqual(1);
    // expect(history.last()).toContain('1 + 2'); //error here

    firstNumber.sendKeys(3);
    secondNumber.sendKeys(5);
    go.click();

    expect(history.count()).toEqual(2);
    // expect(history.first()).toContain('3 + 5'); //and here
});
```

regarding to this [ElementArrayFinder API](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first) it should be run fine

i'm using

- jasmine-1.3.1
- protractor version 1.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to *expect the element's text* instead:

```
expect(history.last().getText()).toContain('1 + 2');
expect(history.first().getText()).toContain('3 + 5');
```